# Redirecting to a controller from a view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to redirect to a controller at the click event of a button.  The controller file is practiceTest.php.  It has an index function that redirects to another view from there.  Unfortunately, I keep getting a 404 not found error.

The relevant code:

```
<input style='position: absolute; right: 0;' type="button" id='rounded_practice' value="Begin Practice" onClick="location.href='/practiceTest'">
```

Any help spotting what I may have missed would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of CI? Are you running on Windows,Mac or Linux? Can you access the controller via the URL?

Comment: It's version 2.2.2 of CI.  I'm running a Mac, and no I cannot access the controller via the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is wrong.If you click on the button You will see you are redirecting wrong URL.You should use full URL instead of relative URL.As you are using CI you can try this way(assumed `practiceTest` is one of your controller name)

```
onClick="location.href='<?php echo site_url('practiceTest');?>'">
```

Comment: That works.  So, do I need to use the site_url call every time I want to call a controller, or is it just because it was in the onClick call of the button?  And thanks for the help!

Comment: Best way to use `site_url('controller_name')` to produce links

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `base_url();/pathforyourcontrollername`